# PhpStorm Deployment - Map branch to remote folder

Tags: git, phpstorm

Let's say I have a project with multiple git branches.

Of course I have setup a deployment in PhpStorm with default mapping of local to remote folder, and this was OK till I was in development stage.

Now that site is live, I wanted to setup something more appropriate. Basically, I wanted to have two mappings.

One mapping would map my local folder `/var/www/html/project/` to my remote folder `/production/public_html/` when I'm on a `master` branch, and second mapping would map same local folder to `/staging/public_html` when I'm on `develop` branch.

I wonder if this is possible in PhpStorm. I've been looking around but haven't find anything specific.

Comment: Have a look at these suggestions: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-25732